# How to send pushes with "conditions" to pushwoosh with remote API?

Tags: pushwoosh

I use the pushwoosh remote API and I can send pushes to all users and to just one device, good!
But now Im trying to be able to send pushes to different groups and Im trying to get "conditions" to work. But Im missing something and I don´t know what!

I have first created a tag called "Grupper" as a listtag at pushwoosh.
And it is registering the value "5A" at pushwoosh from the app.

And this is how I try to send a push from my server.

```
var tags="5A"

     var data = {
        "request": {
          "application": applicationId,
          "auth": authKey,
          "notifications": [{
            "send_date": "now",
            "ignore_user_timezone": true,
            "content": {
            "en": pushtext
            },

             "conditions":["Grupper", "EQ", tags]
          }]
        }
      };
```

And here its the "conditions" that is wrong somehow?

If I remove the row with "conditions" then it sends a push to all users, but if I use it, it sends nothing. No errors.

Any input really appreciated, after a couple of days trying, I still don´t know what Im missing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A condition is always an array of arrays, therefore try this:

```
"conditions":[["Grupper", "EQ", tags]]
```

Also, since "Grupper" is a List-type tag, you can only use IN operator with it (see the docs [here](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/createmessage#tag-conditions))

Comment: Thanks Benedict, I tested with "conditions":[["Grupper", "IN", tags]] but it is still not working. I have no idea why!?

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot to mention it in my first reply. For List tags, you must provide the values in an array, too. Try this:

`"conditions":[["Grupper", "IN", ["5A"]]]`

Comment: BENEDICT, YOU ARE THE MAN!!! Finally after many days it works!!! In all docs at pushwoosh and all over the net all examples has been "conditions":["Grupper", "EQ", tags] and nothing else?? THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: Benedict, since you seams to know this stuff. Maybe you know why sending a request with setTags does´t work for me? Im trying to send the request to setTags at pushwoosh with the following.
var=pushtagsName;
     "tags": {
   "Grupper" : pushtagsName
   }
   }
 };

Comment: Sorry, this is what Im trying to set tags with: "Grupper": [pushtagsName1,pushtagsName2]

Comment: Glad to hear it finally worked for you. I didn't understand about the /setTags, though. Again, keep in mind this is a List tag, and you should do something like this:

`"tags": {"Grupper": ["value1", "value2"]}`

Comment: Thanks, but I have tested with that and also with "tags": {"Grupper": [["value1"],[ "value2"]]} but it is not registering it? Any other suggestions? :-)

Comment: Can you possibly escalate this to our support team (help@pushwoosh.com) and provide the hardware id or the push token of your device?